# How to get Query string without JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, header

I work with `express` and `node.js`. The situation as follow. I have a pixel on my client website. It looks like this:

```
<noscript>
    <a href="https://myhost.site"><img src="https://myhost.site/nojs"/></a>
</noscript>
```

It fires on every visit and gives me a `get` request from which I can grab `referer` and get query string. Like this:

```
const url = new URL(req.get('referer'));
console.log(url.search);
```

But there are tools like this one [Referer-control](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/referer-control/hnkcfpcejkafcihlgbojoidoihckciin?hl=en) which can disable the referer in header.

I can easily get query string from landing page with `javascript`. And if `js` is disabled I still can get query from `referer` like I said.

But how to get `referer` if `js` is disabled and `referer` are blocked?

Comment: You say your using express, so why not get it serverside. -> `req.header('Referer');`

Comment: @Keith — Read the last three words of the question again.

Answer (score 0):

The only other option would be to have the client include a copy of the query string from the page in the query string of `https://myhost.site/nojs`

Comment: @Keith — They could use any server-side language they desired.

Comment: Sorry, it's just that you said `be to have the client include a copy`..

Comment: It seems like it is impossible without additional cooperation with client? For example: client can send me this query from his server or add it to my pixel on server side rendering?